# Elastic search sorting: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default

Tags: elasticsearch

I have such field in mapping:

```
 "computedCompanyName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "exact": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "exact"
            },
            "phon": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "phonetic"
            }
          }
        }
```

This name is calculated with usage of some business logic thats why it is named as computed and stored like this in index. Parts that are used to calculate this name will not be present in the index.

I want to sort companies by this field. As u see this property has two representations: exact and phonetic. So depending on user choice I will be sorting on exact or phonetic representation. For example Mötor and Moetor are two repesentations and sortField can be as for example below:

```
 private SearchQuery createDefaultSortingConditions(NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder) {
    nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("computedCompanyName.exact").order(SortOrder.ASC));      
        return nativeSearchQueryBuilder.build();
    }
```

So it above query I will sort documents by computedCompanyName exact representation but I would also like to implemented computedCompanyName.phon sortField.

The problem is that when I execute this I got (what is Fielddata ? and why I got this error ?) :
BTW: this field also has to be searchable and depending if user chooses exac/phonetic search he wants to search its exact or phonetic representation.

```
Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/my_test/my/_search?rest_total_hits_as_int=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [computedCompanyName.exact] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"dfs","grouped":true,"failed_shards":
```

Whats more.. When I change everything to keyword types and try to sort, then i have problem with analyzers which should work for search purposes.

```
Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/rt_test/_mapping/rechtstraegerindexeddata?master_timeout=30s&include_type_name=true&timeout=30s], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
Warnings: [[types removal] Specifying types in put mapping requests is deprecated. To be compatible with 7.0, the mapping definition should not be nested under the type name, and the parameter include_type_name must be provided and set to false.]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [search_analyzer : phonetic] [analyzer : phonetic]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [search_analyzer : phonetic] [analyzer : phonetic]"},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:936)
```

Is it possible to sort by fields with analyzers ? If yes can I use the same computedCompanyName for searching and for sorting ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option is reindex your indice for a new mapping like this:

```
"computedCompanyName": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "exact": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "exact"
            },
            "phon": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "phonetic"
            }, 
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
```

This way you can your search using analyzer and to use "computedCompanyName.keyword" to sort.

Comment: Ok but what would be the name of field for phonetic and for exact approach ? Or I would not be able to sort by phonetic representation of Mötor Company ? I was wondering if then sorting will work correctly if I have word Mötor and Motor.